# Javascript - Strange regex behaivor

Tags: javascript, regex, string

So this is my code:

```
var str = "eee";

console.log(str.replace(/ee/g, "e*e"));
```

In the console the result is:

```
> "e*ee"
```

When it should be:

```
> "e*e*e"
```

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use positive  lookahead because of overlapping of matches.

```
> var str = "eee";
undefined
> console.log(str.replace(/e(?=e)/g, "e*"));
e*e*e
```

`e(?=e)` , this regex which uses  positive lookahead would match the letter `e` only if it's followed by `e`. Replacing all the matched `e`'s with `e*` will give you the desired output.

Comment: Yes this is really the best way to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Matches "consume" characters. Once the first two `e` characters are matched, there's only one `e` left.

You can re-attempt the substitution repeatedly until the length of the string stops changing, or (much better) use lookahead as in Avinash Raj's answer.

Comment: @AmitJoki yes in this case that might work fine, though it'd match a lone `e` in the middle of the string, which might not be desired.

Comment: So like this: loop(str.len) {str.replace(/ee/, "e*e")}?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski yup. Had that in mind. Hence deleted my comment